# How to return a generic Map from a method in Java

Tags: java, generics, dictionary

I have a parser class which parses the document and returns the parsed data in a Map.

Here is how my classes look.

```
public interface DocumentParser {

        public Map<String, String> parse(Document document);
}


public class ExcelParser implements DocumentParser{

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> parse(Document document) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

}

public interface Document {
    public InputStream getInputStream();
}

public class ExcelDocument implements Document{

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}


public interface DocumentValidator {

    public void validate(Map<String, String> documentData, Map<String, String> referenceData, List<String> referenceKeyList);

}

public class ExcelValidator implements DocumentValidator{

    @Override
    public void validate(Map<String, String> documentData,
            Map<String, String> referenceData, List<String> referenceKeyList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}


public class TestMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Document document = new ExcelDocument();
        DocumentParser parser = new ExcelParser();
        Map<String, String> parsedData =   parser.parse(document);
        DocumentValidator documentValidator = new ExcelValidator();
        documentValidator.validate(parsedData, new HashMap()<String, String>, new ArrayList()<String>);
    }

}
```

Now there could be different type of parser like CSVParser or PDFParser etc.

But I am not sure what type of objects the Map will contain. I do not want to restrict the user of class to return only Map.

User can return even some custom objects too. I want to give that freedom to the user to return any kind of object.

If I do Map explicit cast has to be made while catching the return values from parse method.

Can someone please suggest what could be done to achieve the better design here?

Comment: Then why not just use `Map<String, Object>`? or `Map<Object, String>`? I'm not sure what you are storing in your map.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch will this Map accept String as a key and Person as value?

Comment: It will accept a String and any Object.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If I do public Map<Object, Object> parse(Document document) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return new HashMap<String, String>();
 } it give me a compile time error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<String,String> to Map<Object,Object>".

Comment: Okay. `public Map<?, ?> parse(Document document)`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I had tried that option, But this way you have to have explicit cast in the main method at the statement Map<String, String> parsedData =   (Map<String, String>) parser.parse(document); And this also give a warning "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Map<capture#1-of ?,capture#2-of ?> to Map<String,String>"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45424/discussion-between-sam-and-elliott-frisch)

Comment: Um, make your classes Generic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, why not simply make your interface generic?

```
public interface DocumentParser<K,V> { 

    Map<K,V> parse(Document document);
}


public class ExcelParser implements DocumentParser<String, String> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> parse(Document document) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

}

public SomeOtherParser implements DocumentParser<String, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> parse(Document document) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }
}
```

**Edit to add from comments:** Your class has already said what the `K` and `V` are explicitly by declaring it implements the interface and filling in the types. So to instantiate your class is just:

```
ExcelParser ep = new ExcelParser(); 
Map<String, String> map = ep.parse(someDocument);

SomeOtherParser sop = new SomeOtherParser();
Map<String, Integer> otherMap = sop.parse(someOtherDoc);
```

You'd do the same thing with your `DocumentValidator` interface:

```
public interface DocumentValidator<K,V> {

    void validate(Map<K, V> documentData, Map<K, V> referenceData, 
                  List<K> referenceKeyList); 

}
```

(I'm guessing there that the last `List` argument contains the same type as the map key)

**One last edit from comments:** You can have as many types as you want in the interface declaration; `<K, V, K2, V2>` is perfectly legal if you really were to need it:

```
public interface DocumentValidator<K, V, K2, V2> {

    void validate(Map<K, V> documentData, Map<K2, V2> referenceData, 
                  List<K2> referenceKeyList); 

}

public class ExcelValidator implements DocumentValidator<String,String,String,Integer>{

    @Override
    public void validate(Map<String, String> documentData,
                         Map<String, Integer> referenceData, 
                         List<String> referenceKeyList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried doing that but I could not modify the classes accordingly. Can you please help me making it with Map<K, V>. I mean I am bit confused what <K, V> would be replaced with? Does that mean If I have a ExcelParser that means I have to declare ExcelParser<K,V> in class declaration? What would that achieve exactly?

Comment: @Sam Edited to use `<K, V>`

Comment: Brian Thanks for the answer. Another doubt I had is if I have another method say validate in DocumentParser class and if that also should return something generic like Prase method returns. How can I do that? Because whatever types has been specified for DocumentParser class have been assigned to T right?

Comment: @Sam you'd just do the same thing with your other interface. Edited again.

Comment: Brian I got what you want to say. But what If the documentData is map if <String, String> and the referenceData is map of <String, Integer>?  Is this really possible to achieve? I mean where we could accommodate the differing the Integer type?

Comment: You can add as many type specifiers as you want .. <K,V,V2>; I didn't know that was an option ;) it also depends on what you're going to *do* with the things being passed in - if it's only for that method you can simply infer the type. One last edit coming up

Comment: Brian I got the answer I can do something like DocumentValidator<K, V, T> and T could be the another type which may correspond to the other type of referenceData.